# Enter edit mode automatically in Qtreeview

Tags: qt, qtreeview

Is there a way to force edit-mode in a qtreeview the moment a new item is created? Currently, I can enter edit mode with a double click by setting the EditTriggers to QAbstractItemView.DoubleClicked. Trying a different approach, I was able to select the newly created item right after creation using setCurrentIndex, but that's pretty much it. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: show your code.

Comment: What about `QAbstractItemView::edit()`?

Comment: @vahancho Brilliant! I can't see how on earth I missed that. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @vahancho said, QAbstractItemView::edit() works perfectly.

Comment: Easy to miss! The API for these complex classes is so huge that I'm sure something in my brain deliberately filters out the most "do what it says on the tin" methods!